# while executing the function when I'm providing i/p [parameter which is not in table I'm getting error; otherwise it gets executed]

Tags: plsql

```sql
create or replace function get_ware_house_master(p_WAREHOUSE_IDS in  varchar2)
     return id_wh_id

is
    l_warehouse_list id_wh.id := id_wh_id();
    str varchar2(300);        
begin

    str := 'SELECT BM(w.wh_id)    
            FROM pod_place_warehouse_mapping_tb W
            where ( W.wh_id  IN  (' ||p_WAREHOUSE_IDS  || '))';

    execute immediate str bulk collect into l_warehouse_list;

    for i in l_warehouse_list.first..l_warehouse_list.last loop  
        dbms_output.put_line(l_warehouse_list(i).wh_id);    
    end loop;    

    return l_warehouse_list;
end get_ware_house_master;
```

How to handle the data which are not present in the table I need to use if `l_warehouse_list = null` then `dbms_output('No DATA FOUND')` but if data is not present in the table mentioned in the function I get below error:

> `numeric or value change error`

Comment: Did you try to handle No data exception?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide information about the error(s) you're seeing.  Thanks.

Comment: yes i have used that but inspite of that i am getting error ora 06502 value or numeric error if data is not present if i use when others it gets handled but i have to use no_data as i need to display a o/p status when no_data_found

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `count()` function on that collection of yours:

```sql
create or replace function get_ware_house_master(p_WAREHOUSE_IDS in  varchar2)
     return id_wh_id
is
    l_warehouse_list id_wh.id := id_wh_id();
    str varchar2(300);        
begin

    str := 'SELECT BM(w.wh_id)    
            FROM pod_place_warehouse_mapping_tb W
            where ( W.wh_id  IN  (' ||p_WAREHOUSE_IDS  || '))';

    execute immediate str bulk collect into l_warehouse_list;

    if l_warehouse_list.count() >0 then
      for i in l_warehouse_list.first..l_warehouse_list.last loop  
        dbms_output.put_line(l_warehouse_list(i).wh_id);    
      end loop;    
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('No data');
    end if;

    return l_warehouse_list;
end get_ware_house_master;
```

Here is how to illustrate the latest with little simplification to your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE id_wh_id AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

create or replace function get_ware_house_master(p_WAREHOUSE_IDS in  varchar2)
     return id_wh_id

is
    l_warehouse_list id_wh_id := id_wh_id();
    str varchar2(300);        
begin

    str := 'SELECT * from dual where ''a''=''' ||p_WAREHOUSE_IDS  || '''';
        dbms_output.put_line(str);  
    execute immediate str bulk collect into l_warehouse_list;


if l_warehouse_list.count() >0 then
    for i in l_warehouse_list.first..l_warehouse_list.last loop  
        dbms_output.put_line(l_warehouse_list(i));    
    end loop;    
else
    dbms_output.put_line('No data');
end if;

    return l_warehouse_list;
end get_ware_house_master;
/

-- and call to the function:
          select get_ware_house_master('sbi') from dual
union all select get_ware_house_master('a')   from dual
;
```